# Research on the psychopathology of rapists

Tags: social-psychology, abnormal-psychology, bias, sexual-assault

Since [not all sexual assaulters are psychopaths or sadists](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/dsm5-in-distress/201104/most-rapists-are-not-sadists) as the media often chalks them up to ,there is scope to at least mend the thinking of some of the rapists, or any which haven't yet given in to the temptation.

I have also read up a bit on [different types rapists](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/articles/199211/round-rapists). Most alarming are [juvenile rapists](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/the-love-wisdom/201411/the-norman-high-school-rapes-and-sexism) and their reasoning.
There are short films such as [this](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/talking-about-trauma/201811/man-monster)
I am trying to understand this topic more deeply,as a means to educate people as I asked [here.](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/26029/techniques-to-combat-sexism-at-school-level)

Any further research on this topic and related articles with links are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19112/7604